# How to route Aeron UDP connection inside K8s?

Tags: kubernetes, udp, aeron

We have a cluster of Aeron running outside of K8s, and some number of clients running inside K8s. Because we may have a number of pods per client need to route cluster incoming traffics to the pod but couldn't find a solution. Because traffics are routed as a round-robin between pods and it causes a response of a message not delivered to the right pods.

To clarify my question let's review the process of the open session. The client sent an open session but the response of the open session couldn't be returned to the client and may be passed to another pod.